# Multiple development environments for one project in IntellijIDEA

Tags: maven, web, intellij-idea, project

I am developing large web project, using **IntellijIDEA (11.1.3)**.

I would like to have some environment, where I will be working under HTML templates. I won't use any server-side programming there, just `HTML` markup, `CSS` style sheets and `JavaScript`.

As well, I need different environment, where I will create dynamic application, using not only markup, style sheets and client-side programming, but also `Maven`, `Spring MVC`, `Hibernate`, `PostgreSQL` and, probably, other technologies.

I will use **Tomcat** to deploy both my template and my final application into container to view it in browser.

The question is how to structure my project?

That would be absolutely great if someone could show me step-by-step instructions of creating sample project, but any advises are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA 11 has a special **Web** module type for the plain HTML/JS projects, create one module of this type and another **Java** module for the rest of the technologies.

Comment: Now my project structure is like `./App/src/main/java/` and `./App/src/main/resources/` for java classes, `./App/src/main/webapp/` for web application, and `./App/template/` for templates. Could you please tell me how to create two different artifacts for `templates` and for `webapp` ? I set different folders as `web resource directory` for artifacts , but tomcat always loads contents of `./App/template/`.